# Display the weight of an order on the cart

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I created a view that displays the weight of each product in my cart.
I multiply field quantity by field price unit.
I want to display the total weight of my cart.
How do you do this without going through additional modules ?

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'commerce_order_weight';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'commerce_order';
$view->human_name = 'Poids de la commande';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Poids panier';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  7 => '7',
  3 => '3',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Appliquer';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relation: Commande Drupal Commerce : Referenced line items */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['id'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['table'] = 'field_data_commerce_line_items';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['field'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Relation: Commerce Line item : Referenced products */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_product_product_id']['id'] = 'commerce_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_product_product_id']['table'] = 'field_data_commerce_product';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_product_product_id']['field'] = 'commerce_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_product_product_id']['relationship'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
/* Relation: Commerce Product : Referencing Nœud */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_produit']['id'] = 'field_produit';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_produit']['table'] = 'commerce_product';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_produit']['field'] = 'field_produit';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_produit']['relationship'] = 'commerce_product_product_id';
/* Champ: Commande Drupal Commerce : Identifiant (ID) de la commande */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['id'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['table'] = 'commerce_order';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['field'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Champ: Commerce Product : Poids */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['id'] = 'field_weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['table'] = 'field_data_field_weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['field'] = 'field_weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['relationship'] = 'commerce_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['click_sort_column'] = 'weight';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_weight']['group_column'] = 'entity_id';
/* Champ: Commerce Line Item : Quantité */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['id'] = 'quantity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['table'] = 'commerce_line_item';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['field'] = 'quantity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['relationship'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['precision'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['quantity']['separator'] = '';
/* Champ: Global : Expression mathématique */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['id'] = 'expression';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['field'] = 'expression';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['precision'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['separator'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['expression'] = '[field_weight]*[quantity]';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = 'Le poids de votre commande est actuellement de [expression] kg.
Vous pouvez consulter la grille tarifaire ICI.';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Filtre contextuel: Commande Drupal Commerce : Identifiant (ID) de la commande */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['id'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['table'] = 'commerce_order';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['field'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['exception']['title'] = 'Tout';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['default_argument_type'] = 'commerce_cart_current_cart_order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['order_id']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Critère de filtrage: Commande Drupal Commerce : Type de commande */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'commerce_order';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'commerce_order' => 'commerce_order',
);

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$translatables['commerce_order_weight'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Poids panier'),
  t('plus'),
  t('Appliquer'),
  t('Réinitialiser'),
  t('Trier par'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Line items referenced by commerce_line_items'),
  t('Products referenced by commerce_product'),
  t('Nœud referencing products from field_produit'),
  t('.'),
  t('Le poids de votre commande est actuellement de [expression] kg.
Vous pouvez consulter la grille tarifaire ICI.'),
  t('Tout'),
  t('Block'),
);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try this module? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator

Comment: @cobenash Yes, but I'm looking for a way to do this without module

Comment: I think if you just want to add total weight as a single data at the bottom of the views. you can write some php code at the footer of the views.

Comment: @cobenash Yes that's it. But I do not know the php. What should I do ?

Comment: @cobenash I tried to set the aggregation parameter to "sum" but it does not work.

Comment: I think you need to set 'SUM' the aggregation settings  of the Math expression. Then, you will get only single row as a block.

Comment: @cobenash This is what i did, but it does not work

Comment: The mathematical expression field can not be aggregated

Comment: maybe you should try to write some php or you need to wait for others suggestions. ：）

Comment: Should I create a .tpl in my theme ?

Comment: you can do that too. But if you are not familiar with the views tpl and theme, I think you can simply write the php at the footer of the views.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this?